# How can we programmatically select a tab in Nav bar of JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, navbar

How can we programmatically select a tab in Nav bar of JQuery Mobile? I tried the below code to do that. But of no use.

```
var tabButton = document.getElementById("tabId2");
tabButton.className = "ui-btn-active";
```

**UPDATE:**

Please Check this:  http://jsfiddle.net/YnxML/15/

**UPDATE:**

Following is the code I have used to develop a Navigation  bar at the footer.

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="option-page">
<div data-role="footer" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id ="tabId1"onclick="method1();" >1</a></li>

        <li><a href="#" id ="tabId2" onclick="method2();"  >2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id ="tabId3" onclick="method3();">3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

Comment: That code works on jsfiddle in Chrome (although the style is a bit off), what are you seeing on the phone? Is it just not changing the tab at all?

Comment: Yes Town.....It does not change the Tab selection..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Live Link: http://jsfiddle.net/YnxML/24/

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="option-page">
    <div data-role="footer" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" id ="tabId1"onclick="method1();" >1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id ="tabId2" onclick="method2();"  >2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id ="tabId3" onclick="method3();">3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#tabId1').removeClass('ui-btn-hover-b').addClass('ui-btn-up-b');
$('#tabId2').addClass('ui-btn-active');

$('#option-page').page();
```

Comment: Phill..Great ..Thanks..You are great at JQM..providing solutions for all the questions I have asked..:)

Comment: Can you explain what happens in this line: $('#tabId1').removeClass('ui-btn-hover-b').addClass('ui-btn-up-b');

Comment: it removes the unwanted class and adds the needed class. If you look under chromes dev tools or firebug you can see the classes that jQM adds (even when you hover, click, etc...). Just find the desired classes (look). Here is the breakdown: $('#tabId1') ,<-- finds the element, removeClass('ui-btn-hover-b') <-- removes the unwanted class, addClass('ui-btn-up-b') <-- adds the desired class. I'm just chaining the actions together to save on code and IMHO it's a little easier to read. Glad to help ;)

Comment: Thanks Phill..That answers my question. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#tabId").trigger("click");
```

This trigger will fire click event hence do not require to add or remove "active" from tabs.