# Select value of navbar via code (jquery)

Tags: jquery, select, navbar

I have a navbar on the top of my page where people can select a city.
Everytime they close the app, they have to reselect the city, because I can't find a way to automatically select (visually) the correct city when booting the app.

How can I do this?

```
<div data-role="navbar">
<ul>
       <li id="navBrugge"><a href="#" data-transition="none" data-icon="home"> Brugge </a> </li>
       <li id="navGent"><a href="#" data-transition="none" data-icon="home"> Gent </a></li>
        <li id="navKortrijk"><a href="#" data-transition="none" data-icon="home"> Kortrijk </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: You could save the selected city id in a cookie and re-select it based on that cookie on page load.

Comment: I'm going to that, but I don't know how to select a value via code (after taking the choosen value out of the LocalStorage)

Comment: You can select the correct nav element by using `$('#element_id')` where `element_id` is the id of the list item. I am assuming you have an onclick handler bound to those items, so you can call that function using `$('#element_id').click()`

Comment: I guess you don't exactly understand me completely. This is not going about the coding aspect, but the visual aspect. I want to use code to visually change the appearance of the navbar. But I guess I found a solution over here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407868/how-can-we-programmatically-select-a-tab-in-nav-bar-of-jquery-mobile)

Comment: I apologize for not quite understanding. Glad you found a solution!